# Can not update form when using onComplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I have a `confirmDialog` which i want after clicking on `yes` do some action and after that update specific form and finally hide confirm dialog, but when i use `update=":form"`, dialog does not hide

here is my confirmDialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="changeTimeDialog" header="Time expired"
                 closeOnEscape="true"
                 severity="alert" global="true"
                 message="change Start Time">
    <p:commandButton process="@this" value="yes" icon="ui-icon-check"
                     actionListener="#{bean.changeTime}"
                     oncomplete="PF('changeTimeDialog').hide()" update=":form"/>
    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['no']}" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" 
                     icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="PF('changeTimeDialog').hide()"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Could you try with `@form` instead?

Comment: For starters, if something appears to fail silently in client or server side, ALWAYS read the logs in the client and server side for clues and include this information in the question, also if there's nothing in the log.

Comment: A wild guess would be that your `confirmDialog` is being placed inside to form that is targeted by the update! if that's so, try to move the `confirmDialog` into another form, or update a specific part rather than the whole form.

Comment: thank you @HatemAlimam , yes your guess was true

Comment: You're welcome my friend :)